# Zoom H5 preamps vs Zoom F4

Tags: field-recording, audio-interfaces, zoom

I have done a lot of research on the F4 and my question is related to the preamps of both devices. I have a H5 and love it, but want to up my game and want to know if the difference between the two is that noticeable? Yes, it is possible to record in 96khz with the H5, but this only applies to stereo files. Problematic when you need to record mono using the NTG4+, which only allows up to 48khz

I am a start up sound designer and am into field recordings. I have a NTG4+ and Blimp, but want to get a NT4 for stereo recordings as well. Till now I have been using the Zoom X/Y mic capsules for stereo recording, but I hate the capsule's noise floor for starters, thus the need for a proper mic. The question is, is it worth it selling the H5 and getting a F4? Will the difference be that noticeable when it comes to sound?

Or,should adding the NT4 be enough for now?

Comment: If you do stereo recordings, be sure you have the same Mic for left and right. If you have the 4+, get another 4+, not the regular 4.